# Failed to bypass web push notification using accept / dismiss in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox, browser

[[image]]

I tried to click allow or block on the web notification. Using `switch_to.alert` and `Alert.accept()`  didn't work.
Would any of you help me, please.

Is there any other way to handle this notification in Firefox?

Comment: did you try,  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})?

Comment: with 2 should disable/block notifications and 1 to allow

Comment: @AjeetVerma
AttributeError: type object 'Options' has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'

Comment: Please post the code snippet you're trying to get the solution to your problem.

Comment: @AjeetVerma
here, my code. it gave me a new error and the prompt notification is still can't be clicked.

Comment: ````
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element(By.ID, "email").send_keys("michel@gmail.com")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/input").send_keys("pass123")
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[4]/button").click()
time.sleep(2)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10)
wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())

alrt = driver.switch_to.alert
Alert(alrt.driver).accept()
````

Comment: can you share the URL if it's public because it's difficult to get the root cause https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example